# argocd: How to override imagetag with git SHA in argocd manifest file?

Tags: git, continuous-deployment, helm3, argocd

Below is part of my values.yaml
values.yaml

```yaml
image:
  tag: "${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}"
```

While running the installtion in git CI, I can easily pass the override as below.

```bash
helm install <release name> --set image.tag=${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}  <chart name>
```

Now, We have written the argocd application manifest to install the helm. But not sure how can we pass refer and pass commit SHA id as image tag override.

argocd manifest file as below.

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: my-app
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  destination:
    namespace: my-app
    server: 'https://destination-cluster'
  project: default
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      prune: true
      selfHeal: true
  source:
    repoURL: 'https://my-git-service/repo/my-app.git'
    path: chart/my-app
    targetRevision: main
    helm:
      image.tag: <Here-I-Need-SHA-Value>
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: rather than modify the application manifest, you can just update a values.yaml with this; at my current company, we manage our application manifest values overrides using a tool called `yq`. After a change is made, a PR is created/merged and synced automatically, resulting in a change!

Answer (score 0):

You can use four [different methods](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/helm/) at time of writing:

You can use [`spec.source.helm.parameters`](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/helm/#helm-parameters)

```yaml
source:
  helm:
    parameters:
    - name: "image.tag"
      value: "my-image-tag"
```

*or* [`spec.source.helm.valueFiles`](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/helm/#values-files) to reference a values file:

```yaml
source:
  helm:
    valueFiles:
    - values-overide.yaml
```

*or* [`spec.source.helm.valuesObject`](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/helm/#values) for providing them as in object:

```yaml
source:
  helm:
    valuesObject:
      image:
        tag: "my-image-tag"
```

*or* [`spec.source.helm.values`](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/helm/#values) for providing in-line values:

```yaml
source:
  helm:
    values: |
      image:
        tag: "my-image-tag"
```

A full Argo CD helm app using `spec.source.helm.valuesObject` to pass in `image.tag` to the [bitnami sealed secrets helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/sealed-secrets):

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: sealed-secrets
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  project: default
  destination:
    server: "https://kubernetes.default.svc"
    namespace: kubeseal
  source:
    chart: bitnamicharts/sealed-secrets
    repoURL: oci://registry-1.docker.io
    targetRevision: 1.5.3
    helm:
      releaseName: sealed-secrets
      valuesObject:
        image:
          tag: "0.24.0-debian-11-r0"
```